# Setup a default PHP page in the DocumentRoot of CentOS 6.4 web server

Tags: apache, centos6, document-root

I'm trying to set up my web site in a hosting server which is running CentOS 6.4. The domain has been already set up.

I have checked the `DocumentRoot` in the Apache config file. It is `var/www/html`. So, I added a new file "index.php" in that directory. The file is just echoing `phpinfo()`.

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

But, when I browse `mydomain.com`, I just see the Web Server's Default Page with Parallels Panel. I think `var/www/html/index.php` should be running.

What I still need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my domain needs a hosting setup. When I set up a hosting for the domain, I got a document root `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs` and it FTP information. I think it is just like a virtual host setup. Eventually, `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/index.php` is made running from `mydomain.com`.

When I add a new sub-domain, I got `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mysubdomain.com/` as a document root for that sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

To rectify the issue, please log in to PP under admin and browse "Domains" -> domain.tld -> "Domain Administrator Access." Check the "www" check-box and click "OK."